# How to serialize a special json with Gson (content of object instand of object)

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I use Java + Gson and I want serialize a special json. I want content of object instand of object.

```
{
    "age": 26,
    "email": "norman@futurestud.io",
    "isDeveloper": true,
    "name": "Norman",

    "userAddress": {
        "city": "Magdeburg",
        "country": "Germany",
        "houseNumber": "42A",
        "street": "Main Street"
    }
}
```

is it possible serialize to:

```
{
    "age": 26,
    "email": "norman@futurestud.io",
    "isDeveloper": true,
    "name": "Norman",
    "city": "Magdeburg",
    "country": "Germany",
    "houseNumber": "42A",
    "street": "Main Street"
}
```

I try use this code but wrong:

```
@Expose
private final String age;
...
@Expose
@JsonAdapter(UserAddressSerializer.class)
private final UserAddress userAddress;
...


public class UserAddressSerializer implements JsonSerializer<UserAddress > {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(UserAddress src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        result.add("name", new JsonPrimitive(src.getName()));
        result.add("city", new JsonPrimitive(src.getCity()));
        result.add("country", new JsonPrimitive(src.getCountry()));
        result.add("houseNumber", new JsonPrimitive(src.getHouseNumber()));
        result.add("street", new JsonPrimitive(src.getStreet()));
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: In your Serializer you still use the ``ErrorCode`` type from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599504/serialize-deserialize-a-pojo-contain-a-speciel-enum-not-enum-of-string-with-gs).

Comment: Gson does not support flattening out of box. Also, you are trying to flatten an inner object. In general, you must write a serializer for the outer object that holds the `UserAddress` instance.

Comment: Also I'm not sure that norman is happy to find his email adress published here...

Comment: you can use gson.fromJson and gson.toJson . here is the full description https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization

Comment: I edit my code with `ErrorCode` to `UserAddress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution with use Gson tools (class `UserAddressAdapter extends TypeAdapter<UserAddress>`).

```
public class User {

    ...

    // see the first ligne of UserAddressAdapter#write
    // city => (out.value(value.getCity());)
    @SerializedName("city")
    @JsonAdapter(UserAddressAdapter.class)
    private final UserAddress userAddress;
    ...

}


public class UserAddressAdapter extends TypeAdapter<UserAddress> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, UserAddress value) throws IOException {
        out.value(value.getCity());
        out.name("country");
        out.value(value.getCountry());
        out.name("houseNumber");
        out.value(value.getHouseNumber());
        out.name("street");
        out.value(value.getStreet());
    }

    @Override
    public UserAddress read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final int city = in.nextInt();
        UserAddress[] scopes = UserAddress.values();
        for (UserAddress scope : scopes) {
            if (scope.getCity() == city) {
                return scope;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

and caller is:

```
new Gson().toJson(new User("...", ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON trees are what you are looking for.
But at least one caveat here is sharing same-named property names among different objects.

Suppose you have the following data classes:

```java
final class User {

    final String email;
    final String name;
    final int age;
    final boolean isDeveloper;

    User(final String email, final int age, final String name, final boolean isDeveloper) {
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.isDeveloper = isDeveloper;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("email", email)
                .add("name", name)
                .add("age", age)
                .add("isDeveloper", isDeveloper)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

```java
final class UserAddress {

    final String country;
    final String city;
    final String street;
    final String houseNumber;

    UserAddress(final String country, final String city, final String street, final String houseNumber) {
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("country", country)
                .add("city", city)
                .add("street", street)
                .add("houseNumber", houseNumber)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

Now you can have an utility method to serialize multiple objects into a single `JsonObject` instance.
Also, you can easily have a deserialization counter-part that can deserialize multiple objects from a `JsonObject` instance.
For example:

```
final class JsonObjects {

    private JsonObjects() {
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    static JsonObject combine(final Gson gson, final Map.Entry<Object, ? extends Type>... objectAndTypeEntries) {
        return Stream.of(objectAndTypeEntries)
                // Each element should be serialized to a JsonElement
                .map(e -> gson.toJsonTree(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                // That must be a JSON object
                .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
                // And now we can collect a stream of JsonObject instances into a super-object
                .collect(Collector.of(
                        JsonObject::new, // We'll collect into a new JsonObject instance, this is the accumulator
                        JsonObjects::mergeInto, // Merge each consecutive JsonObject instance into the accumulator
                        JsonObjects::mergeInto, // Or even combine multiple accumulators
                        Function.identity() // And just return the accumulator
                ));
    }

    static List<?> split(final Gson gson, final JsonObject jsonObject, final Type... types) {
        return Stream.of(types)
                // Each element should be deserialized from the JsonObject by a type
                .map(type -> gson.fromJson(jsonObject, type))
                // And just collect all the deserialized objects to a list
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), Collections::unmodifiableList));
    }

    private static JsonObject mergeInto(final JsonObject to, final JsonObject from) {
        for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : from.entrySet() ) {
            to.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        return to;
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```java
final User beforeUser = new User("norman@localhost", 26, "Norman", true);
System.out.println("BEFORE User: " + beforeUser);
final UserAddress beforeUserAddress = new UserAddress("Germany", "Magdeburg", "Main Street", "42A");
System.out.println("BEFORE User address: " + beforeUserAddress);
final JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObjects.combine(
        gson,
        new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(beforeUser, User.class),
        new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(beforeUserAddress, UserAddress.class)
);
System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonObject);
final List<?> objects = JsonObjects.split(gson, jsonObject, User.class, UserAddress.class);
final User afterUser = (User) objects.get(0);
System.out.println("AFTER User: " + afterUser);
final UserAddress afterUserAddress = (UserAddress) objects.get(1);
System.out.println("AFTER User address: " + afterUserAddress);
```

Output:

```
BEFORE User: User{email=norman@localhost, name=Norman, age=26, isDeveloper=true}
BEFORE User address: UserAddress{country=Germany, city=Magdeburg, street=Main Street, houseNumber=42A}
JSON: {"email":"norman@localhost","name":"Norman","age":26,"isDeveloper":true,"country":"Germany","city":"Magdeburg","street":"Main Street","houseNumber":"42A"}
AFTER User: User{email=norman@localhost, name=Norman, age=26, isDeveloper=true}
AFTER User address: UserAddress{country=Germany, city=Magdeburg, street=Main Street, houseNumber=42A}
```

As you can see, you don't need to create extra DTO classes to cover all the cases, but this also requires a little more memory usage due to the use of trees here.